# Apache Flume with Flat Files Source

Tags: hdfs, flume

I have the source directory with many log files coming in and I want to use the Apache Flume to consume this log files and transfer the data to HDFS. I am just wondering how does the Flume knows, the already processed log files? is there any configuration?

Answer (score 0):

The kind of data ingestion you talk about, i.e. consuming files as they are put in a directory, is achieved through the [Spooling Directory Source](https://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html#spooling-directory-source). If you have a look on the documentation your will see that:

> This source lets you ingest data by placing files to be ingested into a “spooling” directory on disk. This source will watch the specified directory for new files, and will parse events out of new files as they appear. The event parsing logic is pluggable. **After a given file has been fully read into the channel, it is renamed to indicate completion (or optionally deleted).**